# Compare dataframes with diffrent amount of rows - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I am working on a program that would allow me to output differences of two csv files. Below is example with some dummy data.

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['vegetable', 100, 'orange', 12, 'carrot'],
                  ['fruit', 150, 'green', 10, 'apple'],
                  ['vegetable', 175, 'white', 3, 'colifower'],
                  ['fruit', 210, 'orange', 1, 'tangerine'],
                  ['vegetable', 75, 'black', 120, 'old_carrot']],
                  columns=['type', 'weight', 'colour', 'days_in_basket', 'name'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['vegetable', 100, 'orange', 12, 'carrot'],
                  ['fruit', 150, 'green', 10, 'apple'],              
                  ['fruit', 200, 'red', 1, 'apple'],
                  ['vegetable', 500, 'green', 2, 'cabbage'],
                  ['vegetable', 170, 'white', 4, 'colifower'],
                  ['fruit', 210, 'orange', 1, 'tangerine'],
                  ['vegetable', 70, 'black', 122, 'very_old_carrot']],
                  columns=['type', 'weight', 'colour', 'days_in_basket', 'name'])
```

**Desired output:**

```
extra_df = pd.DataFrame([['fruit', 200, 'red', 1, 'apple'],
                        ['vegetable', 500, 'green', 2, 'cabbage']],
                        columns=['type', 'weight', 'colour', 'days_in_basket', 'name'])

changed_df = pd.DataFrame([['vegetable', '175 -> 170', 'white', '3 -> 4', 'coliflower'],
                         ['vegetable', '75 -> 70', 'black', '120 -> 122', 'carrot']],
                         columns=['type', 'weight', 'colour', 'days_in_basket', 'name'])
```

As we have no key (ID) problem is to match changed rows from two dataframes and distinct the rows that are completely new.

To overcome this I came up with following concept:
Define key choosing multiple columns (and raise exception if key is not unique), then sort rows using defined key, cut away excessive rows (number of rows in second dataframe is always higher) and compare dataframes.
Defining a key is on a user side.

I have no clue how to use MultiIndex as a key or if MultiIndex is the right way to achieve my goal. Maybe there is whole different approach ex. outer merge? I have looked at multiple solutions but none of them covers adding a key and sorting.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Could you add sample input with desired output cases?

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: Sounds like defining a key is really up to you (the analyst), and not really something that would be solved here

Comment: Thank you guys for your attention, I'll try to follow your advices and edit my post.

Comment: @zipa input->oputput examples added

Comment: @MaxU post edited.

Comment: @djk47463 Yes, definig a key should be on user side (as an argument for a function)

Answer (score 1):

First left outer join the two dataframe together.

```
>>> combined_df=df2.merge(df1,on=['type','colour','name'],how='left') 
>>> combined_df
        type  weight_x  colour  days_in_basket_x        name  weight_y  \
0  vegetable       100  orange                12      carrot     100   
1      fruit       150   green                10       apple     150  
2      fruit       200     red                 1       apple     NaN   
3  vegetable       500   green                 2     cabbage     NaN   
4  vegetable       170   white                 4   colifower     175   
5      fruit       210  orange                 1   tangerine     210   
6  vegetable        70   black               122  old_carrot      75   

   days_in_basket_y  
0              12 
1              10 
2             NaN  
3             NaN  
4               3  
5               1  
6             120
```

When The two dataframes are joined together , the extra rows in df2 will have Nan in the columns from df1.
So, we need to filter those rows with Nan to get the extra_df .

```
>>> extra_df=df2[combined_df['weight_y'].isnull()].reset_index(drop='True')
>>> extra_df
        type  weight colour  days_in_basket     name
0      fruit     200    red               1    apple
1  vegetable     500  green               2  cabbage
```

To get the change_df, first the extra rows needed to be removed.Also, rows without any change are needed to be removed.

```
>>> no_extra_df=combined_df[~combined_df['weight_y'].isnull()]
>>> changed_df_temp=no_extra_df[(no_extra_df['weight_x']!=no_extra_df['weight_y']) & (no_extra_df['days_in_basket_x']!=no_extra_df['days_in_basket_y'])].reset_index(drop=True)
>>> changed_df_temp
        type  weight_x colour  days_in_basket_x        name  weight_y  \
0  vegetable       170  white                 4   colifower     175   
1  vegetable        70  black               122  old_carrot      75   

   days_in_basket_y  
0               3  
1             120
```

Finally the columns weight_x,weight_y and days_in_basket_x,days_in_basket_y should be joined with ->

```
>>> change_df_temp['weight']=change_df_temp.apply(lambda x : str(x['weight_y'])+'->'+str(x['weight_x']),axis=1)
>>> change_df_temp['days_in_basket']=change_df_temp.apply(lambda x : str(x['days_in_basket_y'])+'->'+str(x['days_in_basket_x']),axis=1)
>>> 
>>> change_df=change_df_temp[['type', 'weight', 'colour', 'days_in_basket', 'name']]
>>> change_df
        type      weight colour days_in_basket        name
0  vegetable    175->170  white           3->4   colifower
1  vegetable      75->70  black       120->122  old_carrot
```

Comment: Thank you, this resolution looks really good.
What concerns me me is the key and sorting I mentioned in my question. In your answer `on=['type','colour','name']` is responsible for choosing _the key_.
In my example of output I made a mistake and you probably changed `very_old_carrot` to `old_carrot` to get the right answer. But let's assume that we have inputs as they were defined at the beginning. Using 'type', 'colour' and 'name' we will loose change of `old_carrot` name. How to detect this situation and rise an exception?

Comment: This answer works only for provided 'dummy' values. I would like to use this program for different csv files / dataframes.